# How to properly initialize and terminate EGL on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

While there are many samples around about using OpenGL ES on Android all of them seems to be incorrect (even ones come with Android SDK/NDK) in respect to initialization/termination of EGL. And source of problem is just in Android application model which make correct using of EGL weird.

The real problem that EGL initialized per OS's ***process*** while all Android samples and even **GLSurfaceView** (actually most of samples just use it) involve the EGL initialization/termination per ***Component*** (Activity or WallpaperService). And this is completely wrong due to the fact that all components are running in same process! There is no problem if application consist of just one component but this is an issue if there are multiple components in application and they are using OpenGL ES each.

Just consider the situation when two application's components which use the OpenGL ES runs at same time and one of them finished. On finishing such component will call the **eglTerminate()** (Look in **GLSurfaceView** source code to see what I am talking about) and this will terminate the EGL for whole **process**! And any EGL calls from another already running component will fail starting from this moment!

I have check for tons of examples and all of them initialize and terminate EGL per component basis (actually no one I have seen do something different than **GLSurfaceView** do, most of them just copy of **GLSurfaceView** internals).

And now I am interesting in find a *"proper"* way to get working (with respect to initialization/termination) with EGL on Android.

The "proper" way should provide:

1. EGL initialization when any first component using EGL is started
2. EGL termination when last component using EGL is finished
3. Multithreading. There is should not be restriction on EGL manipulation only from main application thread.

Please note that (2) is essential to minimize the system resources usage by application when there is no active entities which use the EGL/OpenGL ES.

Any ideas? Or maybe I have overlooked something about the EGL on Android?

### Update

There is another interesting related issue:

Due to the fact that only one active rendering context is allowed per thread, only one Component at same time may use OpenGL ES from main thread normally. Having more than one Component which use the OpenGL ES in main thread running at same time will lead to problems because last component calling **eglMakeCurrent()** will implicitly "substitute" all other Components' contexts by his own one (and this actually will completely broke the components logic).

### Update 2 (final)

It was revealed (thanks to **Romain Guy**) that Android actually has an internal workaround for EGL initialization/termination issue in a form of explicit (it is against the EGL specification and not mentioned in the Android documentation) "reference counting" inside the **eglInitialize()** and **eglTerminate()**.

Comment: My approach is to put all of the OGL activity in one component, even though other components generate events for it. That avoids the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

eglTerminate() and eglInitialize() are reference counted so it's okay for each "component" to invoke them. On Android 3.0 in particular, it is very common to have several OpenGL contexts in the same app, and there is no problem whatsoever with EGL.

Comment: According to the EGL specification the **eglInitialize()** / **eglTerminate()** are not reference counted. And multiple OpenGL contexts are not the issue itself (it is allowed by specification) but actual issue is side effect you may have due to the Android application model. Please note that contexts related issue I am outlined can't be resolved by EGL implementation "automatically" in any way.

Comment: It seems that Android really has the internal reference counting in the **eglInitialize()** / **eglTerminate()** but there are no any words about this in the documentation. Moreover while it is resolve the initialization issue (and makes the Android EGL not conforming specification(!)) there is no solution possible for contexts related issue.

Comment: That's not what the EGL spec says, but that' show it works on Android. The solution to having multiple components using multiple OpenGL contexts on the same thread (which they should not do) is to check the current egl context and do a make current if it's not the correct one. This won't happen with GLSurfaceView for instance since each GLSurfaceView has its own rendering thread.

Comment: Well, so there is an internal workaround but why no info in the documentation ? How should developers know about it ?