# How to get an EGL display/context to a specific GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

This is a follow up to [my original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509588/egl-vs-gles-2-0-on-android-e-g-java), which was probably too broad (whereas this one is probably too specific but maybe I can apply Newton's Method).

My specific situation is: OpenGL ES 2.0, on Android, using only Java (no JNI/Native code).

I am trying to understand how EGL and Android's GLES implimentation work together (or don't). I am having trouble because the EGL interface(API) does not seem well suited to Android's Java centric, Activity based OS.

As a specific example: I have subclassed GLSurfaceView and create an instance using an XML layout and then use `findViewById()` to retrieve a reference. Using this approach I have the [textured triangle example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/GLES20TriangleRenderer.html) working (GLES 2.0 on Android 2.2, API level 8). This example does not use EGL. As a learning exercise I wanted to re-write it using EGL.

All the examples I can find use `eglGetDisplay()` and `eglInitialize()`, and create a context in puff of greasy black smoke. None of the examples, references and questions I have found apply specifically to ES2.0/EGL/Android/Java. Am I completely missing something? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365366/how-to-properly-initialize-and-terminate-egl-on-android) is related (I think) but does not have any responses and the example used in [the ES 2.0 Programming Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321502795) is a stand alone C implementation.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing Android specific to EGL really. When you create an EGL window surface (eglCreateWindowSurface) you give it a Surface or a SurfaceHolder (which a SurfaceView will give you.) This means you can pretty much copy/paste an EGL example from C, C++ or any other language and have it work on Android in minutes. That's how I do it ;-)

Update: I just read your other message. You need EGL to initialize a GLES context.

Comment: So I use .getHolder().getSurface() and pass the Surface returned as the "native_window" to eglCreateWindowSurface()? Or should I pass the Holder to eglGetDisplay(), since I want to double buffer (so I need to use eglCreatePbufferSurface() instead of eglCreateWindowSurface(), right? Maybe?)

Comment: You can just pass the holder directly to eglCreateWindowSurface(). No need to worry about double buffering, it's done for you.